# Excursion areas and bridges for F- and chi(-square)- processes

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes

My question relates to excursion areas (and excursion bridges, in particular) for $\chi$-, $\chi^2$-, gamma- and/or F-distributed stochastic processes (or more general random fields with positive values). I'm finding it difficult to detect any past research work and results on excursion areas for these Gaussian-related processes, which is puzzling. On the other hand, distributions and statistics of excursion $lengths$ have been extensively covered for $\chi^{(2)}$- and F-processes

As far as I am aware, the literature on excursion areas (or volumes, by extension) and bridges seems to focus only on more elaborate processes for increments, such as Brownian, Levy and Bessel processes.

My questions: 
(1) have I missed essential literature on excursion areas for F- and/or $\chi^{(2)}$-processes? Does it feature perhaps under a different title or topic?
(2) if there are indeed no published results on excursion areas for F- and/or $\chi^{(2)}$- or gamma-processes, is there any reason why the results might be trivial (perhaps considered as special cases of either Gaussian or Brownian/Levy/Bessel processes), prohibitive, or having some particular difficulty?

Grateful for any pointers, comments or suggestions.